# Domain name required for sender address

Tags: matlab, email

When I execute the following line from my `auto` user:

```
sendmail('my.email@my.email.com', 'subject', 'body')
```

I get the following error message:

> 553 5.5.4 ... Domain name required for sender address auto

However, if I execute the same line from my `myUser` account it workes.

I already set:

```
setpref('Internet','SMTP_Server','<...>')
setpref('Internet','E_Mail','<...>')
```

to be the same for both `auto` and `myUser`

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo in

```
setpref('Internet','E_Mail','<...>')
```

which should have been

```
setpref('Internet','E_mail','<...>')
```